# Microsoft security essentials blocking manifest file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, security, ms-security-essentials

When compiling programs with Visual Studio 2010 C++ Express edition I get the error `c101008a`.
Including manifest-files in the ignore list in Microsoft security essentials solves this, but only once, when I compile again, I have to do it again.

Anyone have a solution for this except switching anti-virus software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found several suggestions on the web, such as doing a Clean first.

Comment: You mean scanning for viruses?

Comment: No. Under the Build menu, you'll see Clean. That removes all temporary files (without building), including some that persist between builds.

Comment: This also happens, once you switch from NON-PCH to PCH without making a full build. Yes, Clean helps!